# EPSG.io API for PROJ definitions

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, api

I am trying to use the EPSG.io API to retrieve PROJ definitions for a CRS. I know that they provide them in their website but the API only seems to be able to retrieve in WKT or GML format. Is there a way to get the PROJ definition from an API call?

- API: https://apps.epsg.org/api/swagger/ui/index#!/CoordRefSystem/CoordRefSystem_Export
- Example of WKT call: https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordRefSystem/2004/export/?format=wkt

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the official site epsg.org, not epsg.io that is run by a private company.  EPSG/IOPG supports only the standard formats WKT and GML.  The epsg.io site supports other kind of definitions and the proj4 strings can be captured directly with this syntax `https://epsg.io/3048.proj4`.

The epsg.io site takes the definitions from the EPSG database and from the Proj library but it is not uncommon that epsg.io has errors in their data.

You can also use the projinfo utility from your own computer. Usage example:

```
projinfo epsg:3048 -o PROJ
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=utm +zone=36 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

It is also possible to convert the WKT from the official epsg.org site into Proj with projinfo. The conversion may be lossy because it is not possible to express everything that is possible in WKT as Proj strings. Even the Proj library itself is using WKT as a native format nowadays.

Usage example for Windows where the double quotes in WKT must be escaped with backslash.

```
projinfo -o PROJ "PROJCRS[\"Montserrat 1958 / British West Indies Grid\",BASEGEOGCRS[\"Montserrat 1958\",DATUM[\"Montserrat 1958\",ELLIPSOID[\"Clarke 1880 (RGS)\",6378249.145,293.465,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]],ID[\"EPSG\",7012]],ID[\"EPSG\",6604]],ID[\"EPSG\",4604]],CONVERSION[\"British West Indies Grid\",METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,ID[\"EPSG\",9102]],ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-62,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,ID[\"EPSG\",9102]],ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9995,SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9201]],ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],PARAMETER[\"False easting\",400000,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]],ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]],ID[\"EPSG\",8807]],ID[\"EPSG\",19942]],CS[Cartesian,2,ID[\"EPSG\",4400]],AXIS[\"Easting (E)\",east],AXIS[\"Northing (N)\",north],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]],ID[\"EPSG\",2004]]"

PROJ.4 string:
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-62 +k=0.9995 +x_0=400000 +y_0=0 +a=6378249.145 +rf=293.465 +towgs84=174,359,365,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful!